# AngularJS - $q's Promise not cascading to controller properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller

While I'm reading up on Pluralsight's fundamentals on `AngularJS`, I'm stumped with my `$http + $q.defer()` not working as it should be. It seems like even the `deferred` variable has been resolved, the *change still doesn't cascade onto the controller.*

**My View:**

```
 <li class="row" ng-repeat="item in jsonData.Items">
```

**My Service:**

```
mediaApp.factory('ServiceData', function ($http,$q) {
        return{
            getJson: function ($scope) {
                var deferred = $q.defer();

                $http(
                {
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: url
                }).
                        success(function (data, status, header, config) {


                            $timeout(function () {
                                deferred.resolve(data);
                            });
                        })
        }
```

**My Controller**:

```
$scope.jsonData = ServiceData.getJson($scope);
```

Meanwhile, these lines of code work on the controller:

```
ServiceData.getJson($scope).
       then(function (data) {
           $scope.jsonData = data;
       });
```

Can someone enlighten me on this? I believe the workaround is already proper, but I would like to understand why certain implementations of the code doesn't work as expected.

What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't returning the promise from `getJson`

```
mediaApp.factory('ServiceData', function ($http, $q) {
    return {
        getJson: function ($scope) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'json.json'
            }).
            success(function (data, status, header, config) {
                deferred.resolve(data);

            })
            /* return the promise*/
            return deferred.promise
        }
    }
})
```

Since `$http` returns a promise....you could to the same thing without creating your own deffered and just return the `$http` call

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/HbYAMVhsWPozwM42af6Q?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: As per your first comment, I crawled through the code and saw that $scope.jsonData indeed has a typeof Promise.

For your other input, can you present a better solution? The plunker link doesn't seem to work. Thanks for your help on this.

Comment: plunker site acting slow...but is working. I just updated demo using `$http` promise

Comment: Oh, now I see the difference. $http.get() returns its own Promise object. Meanwhile using deferred really requires the use of .then().For everyone's reference, here is the [LINK](http://markdalgleish.com/2013/06/using-promises-in-angularjs-views/) where I found the supposed shorthand of deferred.resolve(object). Thanks Charlietfl for the clarification.